# How can I generate a dynamic onclick which pass multiple values to a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to pass multiple values from an `onclick` attribute to a function. So I need the `onclick` to be formatted this way `onclick='getLine("1","text");'`

```js
//Ajax call with dynamic onclick
$.ajax({
  url: 'data/tiles-personal.json',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'get',
  cache: false,
  success: function(pdata) {
    $(pdata.tile).each(function(index, value) {
      console.log(value.name, value.id, +'States(' + value.states + ')');
      if (value.name == "MA Auto (Stand Alone)" || value.name == "USLI Events" || value.name == "USLI Personal Lines") {
        document.getElementById("rowP").innerHTML = "<div class='filterrowP' data-state='" + value.states + "'><div class='col-sm-4' style='background-color:#FFFFFF;'>" + "<span class='sm-4-corner'>Coming soon</span>" + "<div name='footprintinfo' class='footprintinfo' style='position:absolute;left:122px;z-index:200;'><a href='##' title='" + value.name + "'><i class='fa fa-info-circle' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>" + "</div><a href='#' onclick='getLine(1," + value.name + ")' class='href-nav'><img src=images/" + value.image + " border='0' class='ind' title='" + value.name + "'/>" + "<div class='tiles-t'>" + value.name + "</div></a></div></div>";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("rowP").innerHTML = "<div class='filterrowP' data-state='" + value.states + "'><div class='col-sm-4' style='background-color:#FFFFFF;'>" + "<div name='footprintinfo' class='footprintinfo' style='position:absolute;left:122px;z-index:200;'><a href='##' title='" + value.name + "'><i class='fa fa-info-circle' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>" + "</div><a href='#' onclick='getLine(1,none);' class='href-nav'><img src=" + value.image + " border='0' class='ind' title='" + value.name + "' />" + "<div class='tiles-t'>" + value.name + "</div></a></div></div>";
      }
    });
  }
});

//function that receives the onclick values
function getLine(initValue, initTxt) {}
```

```html
<!-- div that displays the json data -->
<div id="rowP" class="rowP" style="padding-left: 30px;"></div>
```

Comment: Do you know how to escape quotes in strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use inline event handlers or styling. They are bad practice as they tie the HTML and CSS/JS logic together, which is the opposite of what you want.

Instead, put the unique data in a `data` attribute on the element, then read it back out in a delegated event handler.

Also note that your code is overwriting `innerHTML` in every iteration of the loop, so only the last item will be visible. You should look in to appending the new content instead, something like this:

```html
<div id="rowP" class="rowP"></div>
```

```js
var $row = $('#rowP');
$.ajax({
  url: 'data/tiles-personal.json',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'get',
  cache: false,
  success: function(pdata) {
    pdata.tile.forEach(function(tile) {
      $row.append(`<div class="filterrowP" data-state="${value.states}"><div class="col-sm-4"><span class="sm-4-corner">Coming soon</span><div name="footprintinfo" class="footprintinfo"><a href="#" title="${value.name}"><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div><a href="#" data-name="${value.name}" class="href-nav"><img src="images/${value.image}" border="0| class="ind" title="${value.name}" /><div class="tiles-t">${value.name}</div></a></div></div>`);
    });
  }
});

$row.on('click', '.href-nav', function() {
  var name = $(this).data('name');
  // your logic here...
});
```

```css
#rowP {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.filterrowP {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.footprintinfo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 122px;
  z-index: 200;
}
```

Comment: I followed your suggestions but I'm not getting anything back.

Comment: in fact I'm trying to output "name" to the console log and I get an error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

console.log(${name});

Comment: Well looks like I got it to return all Json objects but the onclick for the tiles still won't trigger

Comment: You're getting the syntax error because you're not using string interpolation properly - however you don't need it there. You can just do `console.log(name);`